# Django : Instance of IntegerField in a model gives type as 'int'

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I was trying to implement some functions defined for the IntegerField .

This is the code:

```
class student(models.Model):
marks=models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0,null=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    print self.marks.has_default()
    return str(self.marks)
```

This is the error I got:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'has_default'
```

I then implemented this code:

```
class student(models.Model):
marks=models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0,null=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    print type(self.marks)
    sample=models.IntegerField()
    print(type(sample))
    return str(self.marks)
```

And this is the ouput I got:

```
<type 'int'>
<class 'django.db.models.fields.IntegerField'>
```

Now,I don't understand why this is happening.
Shouldn't the type for both be the same as both of them are  instances of models.IntegerField()

Comment: For a start, `has_deafult` has a typo: should be `has_default`.

Comment: Corrected the typo but the error is still there as the instance  self.marks is being read as an 'int' type and not as 'class IntegerField' which i don't understand why.

Comment: it's because Django's `Model` has a custom Metaclass which changes the behaviour this way (ie. attributes contains the values, not the instances of the fields)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, django's metaclasses produce this behaviour, which is what you want most of the time: `instance.marks` should give you the marks as an `int`! However, you can access the actual field instance via the [`_meta` API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta):

```
self._meta.get_field_by_name('marks')[0].has_default()
```